# Assigning a value to a global variable from inside of event handler?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I'm working on a program but an issue i was faced to keep me worried.I'm kind of novice and i'm building this program for a competition.The code where the problem lies is like following :

```
class Blabla : Usercontrol
{
    public List<string> mainList;

    public Blabla()
    {
        mainList = new List<string>();
        something.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(xx_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }
    void xx_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> abc = SomeMethod(e.Result);
        mainList = abc;
    }
}
```

I try it.Even though "abc" variable has the value i want , mainList remains empty.I don't know why and how to make it work.That's why i need some hand.Thank you.

Comment: plus.. dose the `SomeMethod()` returns a List<string> ?

Comment: @Rami: Probably yes... otherwise it wouldn't event compile...

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo 'abc' is declared inside of the event handling method. i forgot to add it and edited currently

Comment: As the code looks now ´mainList´ should get a reference to the same list as `abc` contains. Are you sure you looked **after** the assignment of `mainList` (not when the yellow debug marker is on the line, but after) and that nothing else can change `mainList`?

Comment: Important distinction: mainList is not a global variable. It's a field that is a member of class Blabla. It's generally good practice to make all fields private.

Comment: Is the event ever being raised/invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Variable `abc` has the value you want UNTIL you get out of your event handler, probably, when it gets deleted because it uses `e.Result` directly.

Familiarize yourself with `.Clone()` method and `IClonable` interface, and try creating a COPY of the list that is in question, not the reference.

Comment: That's not how C# works. The list will exits and be valid as long as there's a reference pointing to it. By passing/saving a reference the objects stays active. We're not talking about C/C++'s local variables here. Compared to C/C++ C' always uses malloc/new, even when not using any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If abc is a list, mainList will be set to the same list.  You don't have to clone the list, it should stay active because there is a reference to it, and therefore it doesn't get garbage collected.

When you said that mainList was empty, did you look at it in the debugger immediately after setting it in the xx_DownloadStringCompleted method?  Or are you looking at it somewhere else in your program?

I would guess that this is a threading issue.  Does your event handler get called from a different thread?  If so, you would need to add some synchronization logic in order to guarantee that mainList is available to your other thread.